React Native Video "muted" Prop Not Working Consistently on Component Mount
I'm using the react-native-video library in my project, and I'm having an issue with the muted prop. When the video component mounts, the audio is supposed to be muted. However, intermittently, the sound plays for a brief moment (less than a second) before muting. Sometimes the sound doesn't play at all as expected.
I have set the muted state dynamically, true as default. Has anyone encountered this before or have any suggestions on how to ensure the video is muted immediately upon mounting?
Environment:
React Native version: 0.63.3
react-native-video version: 5.2.1
Platform: iOS
